# swift second textview not visible

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have an iOS project I'm working on using Xcode 9.2 and Swift4. I have a UITextView but second the UITextView not visible.

```
let logo: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logoyeni"));
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

let bannerText: UITextView = {
   let textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = "Müziğin Sosyal Medyası";
    textView.textColor = UIColor.salmon;
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return textView
}()

let slogan: UITextView = {
    let textView1 = UITextView()
    textView1.text = "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur";
    //textView.font = UIFont.textStyle3;
    //textView.textColor = UIColor.cloudyBlue;
    textView1.textAlignment = .center;
    textView1.isEditable = false
    textView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return textView1
}()
```

ViewDidLoad =

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(logo);
    view.addSubview(bannerText);
    view.addSubview(slogan);
    setup();
```

and constrains =

```
private func setup(){
    logo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 127).isActive = true
    logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 127).isActive = true

    bannerText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logo.bottomAnchor, constant: 29).isActive = true
    bannerText.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerText.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    slogan.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerText.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    slogan.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    slogan.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    slogan.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

How to fix this problem?

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraints are wrong.

`bannerText.bottomAnchor = view.bottomAnchor`

`slogan.topAnchor = bannerText.bottomAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)`

`slogan.bottomAnchor =  view.bottomAnchor`

This will set the height of the second text view to zero.
You should have a height constraint for at least one of the text views rather than pinning both of them to the bottom of the superView.

Comment: thank you deleted     bannerText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
 and solved

Comment: In that case, if the first text view grows taller, it will push the second text view towards the bottom and eventually, it will go off screen again.

Answer (score 0):

You have pinned the bannerText to the bottom of the logo (offset by 29) and the left, right and bottom of the view.

You have then pinned the slogan to the bottom of the bannerText (offset by 4) and the left, right and bottom of the view.

That's not going to work because the bottom of the bannerText and the bottom of the view are the same and as the top of the slogan is the bottom of the view the top of slogan ends up being the bottom of the view and therefore it is outside the view (the constraints probably break as well).

You need to fix the constraints based on what you want to see.